# Multiple Threads Cannot Access the Same RAMdisk Created by modprobe

Tags: centos, block-device, ramdisk, lsblk, fio

I have created RAMdisks of 60GB using `modprove brd rd_size=62914560` on CentOS 7.5. Checking the results, `fdisk -l /dev/ram*` shows 16 ram block devices of 60GB size (/dev/ram0, /dev/ram1, ..., /dev/ram15).

I want to run 16 jobs (threads) with random accesses on one ram block device to check the performance. I run such a workload using FIO tool. However, I get the following error:

> cache invalidation of /dev/ram1 failed: Device or resource busy

Why this happens? Is there a limitation in the number of jobs (threads) accessing a single ram block device?
When I check the block devices with `lsblk`, the ram block devices are not shown. What is the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked multiple questions in one go which reduces your chances of having them all answered `:-(`

> However, I get the following error:
>
> > cache invalidation of /dev/ram1 failed: Device or resource busy
>
> Why this happens? Is there a limitation in the number of jobs (threads) accessing a single ram block device?

The functionality to free pages used by the brd device was removed in the [`ff26956875c2f05e12ecec9938411a2c7dfc767d: brd: remove support for BLKFLSBUF`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ff26956875c2f05e12ecec9938411a2c7dfc767d#diff-0073fcfd72c2542e5b37afaf42cf759190d859fcb0d7519ce62d310f29862f7a). This was done because issuing `BLKFLSBUF` to a child RAM partition caused damage to the parent BRD device (and I guess potentially other sibling partitions that might have been sharing that page).

> Is there a limitation in the number of jobs (threads) accessing a single ram block device?

No, see above.

> When I check the block devices with lsblk, the ram block devices are not shown. What is the reason?

Because `lsblk` doesn't show RAM block devices by default by design... From the opening of the man page [`lsblk(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html):

> The command prints all block devices (except RAM disks) in a tree-like format by default.

See the [options in the lsblk man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html#OPTIONS) for how you can change what `lsblk` shows.

Answer (score 3):

From the `lsblk` man page:

> The command prints all block devices (except RAM disks) in a tree-like format by default.

It's not a bug, it's a feature! :-)

If you want to include RAM devices, you can do it with `lsblk -I 1`

```
lsblk -I 1
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
ram0    1:0    0  9,8M  0 disk 
ram1    1:1    0  9,8M  0 disk 
ram2    1:2    0  9,8M  0 disk
...
```

Comment: thank you :). Do you know if there's a limitation in the number of threads accessing a single ram block device?